# Error with handle(Event) in EventHandler

Tags: javafx, event-handling, eventhandler, mouseclick-event

I'm new new to javafx and I would like just to print the the coordinates of the mouse click.
I've seen examples but I've got an error in the EventHandler line that I don't understand, it says:

```
anonymous javafxapplication2.JavaFXApplication2$1 is not abstract and does not override abstract method handle(Event) in EventHandler
```

What's the problem? Thanks!

```
package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Line line = new Line();

        Group root = new Group(line);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getX());
                System.out.println(event.getY());
            }
        }
        primaryStage.setTitle("Disegna linee");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm) on javafx handlers I believe your problem is that you need to provide the type to the new `eventHandler` like

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { // Was missing the <MouseEvent>
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) { ... };

    });
```